# add_pval: textsize will not change

Tags: r, annotations

I want to change size of p-values by using `add_pval(textsize=0.1)`, but no matter what I write as textsize, it do not change the size.

example:

```
wert_controls <- c(0.5, 0.4, 2, 0.3, 0.4)
wert_patients <- c(1,2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.1)
g_cont <- rep("controls", length(wert_controls))
g_pat <- rep("patients", length(wert_patients))

nd <- data.frame(gruppe=c(g_cont, g_pat),
                 wert=c(wert_controls, wert_patients))

plot1 <- ggplot(data=nd, aes(x=gruppe, y=wert)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=gruppe))
add_pval(plot1, add=T, pairs=list(c(1,2)), test="wilcox.test", barheight = 0.05, textsize=0.1, pval_text_adj = 0.1, heights = c(2.5))
```

How can I change the size - so that in this case the P=1 is smaller than without defining the size?

Answer (score 0):

Found no solution with add_pval() function. I changed the function to the `stat_compare_means()` function from the ggpubr package.

```
plot1 + stat_compare_means(comparison=c(1,2), method = "wilcox.test", tip.length = 0.05, size=3.25,  vjust = -0.1, label.y = c(2.5))
```

Now with size=value I can change to a size I want.